q suddenly is the screenshot key, f reloads the page, the s and b keys don't do anything
I'm at my wit's end. Since this morning, I can only use my Acer Aspire 3 Spin 14 laptop with my external USB keyboard.
I checked under "Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts" and did not find any changes.
Even when trying a Live USB Ubuntu, the keys keep the changed function.
Edit 1: I'm using Xubuntu 24.10. Also marking this question as closed, as this is most probably a hardware defect. I will return the laptop for a warranty repair.

please [edit] your question with at least some detail about which distro/version you are using together with any other information about what potentially might have triggered this.
